# Saving the intermediate results of a loop

Tags: r

I am trying to learn how to store the intermediate results of loop. That is, if I were to interrupt the loop, the existing results would be available upon interruption.

For example:

```
list_results <- list()

for (i in 1:100000){

    num_1_i = sample(1:100 , 1)
    num_2_i = sample(1:100 , 1)
    num_3_i = sample(1:100 , 1)

inter_results_i <- data.frame(i, num_1_i, num_2_i, num_3_i)
list_results[[i]] <- inter_results_i
}
```

When I interrupt this loop, the existing results seem to have been saved.

**Have I done this correctly?**

Comment: Did you examine the result? does it match your expectation?

Comment: It looks as though it should work.  You could make it a little bit faster by creating `list_results` with 100000 elements from the beginning, so that you don't need to keep growing it.  Use `list_results <- vector("list", length = 100000)` as your first line.

Answer (score 1):

The code you gave is a `for` loop, but the same works in a `while` loop. If the loop modifies a variable with it's output at each iteration, that result will persist after the loop completes or is interrupted.

As user2554330 noted in the comments, if you know a priori how long the result should be, your loop will run a little faster if you create it at that length rather than growing it with each iteration of the loop.

```r
results <- list()

counter <- 2

set.seed(1)
while (counter %% 3 != 0) {
  results[[length(results) + 1]] <- sample(100, counter)
  counter <- counter + sample(2:6, 1)
}

results
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 68 39
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 34 87 43 14
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] 59 51 97 85 21 54 74
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: @ dan adams: thank you so much! I had a typo ... I meant "for" and not "while". Thank you so much!